# Check if serverside div is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I've got a div that's visibility status is determined on the server side and set like so:

```
myDiv.Visible = true;
```

I can't get a proper visibility status on the client side though. I've tried checking:

```
document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_myDiv').style.display
```

to see if it's block or inline. I've checked the visibility property as well. All of these are just set to an empty string.

I also tried using jQuery:

```
if ($('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_myDiv').is(":visible"))
```

but it returns false. I've verified that jQuery is finding the div. How do I reliably check if the div is visible?

Comment: If you run `$('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_myDiv')` in the firebug or chrome console, you can see if jquery can find something with your selector

Comment: I've verified that the div is being found by jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Visible` in .NET does not set the css style, it only affects if the div will be in your html or not. If you set it to false there will be no div at all on the html page.

The empty string you get from the style is probably right, and the property is set to it's default style.

Your jQuery was missing the '#'. `if ($('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_myDiv').is(":visible"))`

In short: just check if the div is present, then you know if it is declared `Visible` on the server.

Comment: The lack of '#' was an error in writing the question. But it is present in my code. I've updated the question to reflect that.